# Unable to open device "/dev/input/event14". Please ensure you have the appropriate permissions

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to the kivy package ,I got a warning while running my program
Unable to open device "/dev/input/event14". Please ensure you have the appropriate permissions.
but the program executed successfully but i dont know why i am getting this warning

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
class PongBall(Widget):
    pass

class PongGame(Widget):
    pass

class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PongGame()

PongApp().run()
```

pong.kv

```
<PongBall>
    size : 50,50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos : self.pos
            size: self.size


<PongGame>
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos :self.center_x-5,0
            size:10,self.height

    Label:
        font_size : 70
        center_x  : root.width/4
        top : root.top-50
        text : "0"

    Label:
        font_size : 70
        center_x  : root.width*3/4
        top : root.top-50
        text : "0"

    PongBall:
        center : self.parent.center
```

Answer (score 0):

If everything seems to work fine then you can safely ignore this, it just means there is an input device not accessible to Kivy's scan.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but for me things are NOT working properly! A new window should open, but it's not. Basically the window freezes, I cant' even close it.